# JIT mode for Tailwind not working in localhost preview in Next JS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, jit

I'm building a Next JS website and running Tailwind with JIT. This is my tailwind.config.js:

```
  module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  extend: {},
  plugins: [],
  };
```

Problem is that every time I write new code I have to restart my server and run 'npm run dev' because it's not updating my CSS on http://localhost:3000/.

I also get a warning when I run my server:

```
warn - You have enabled the JIT engine which is currently in preview.
warn - Preview features are not covered by semver, may introduce breaking changes, and can change at any time.
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?
Thanks!

Comment: I got the same problem for the first time when I upgraded to Next.js 11 and TailwindCSS v2. JIT mode is not working on Localhost but Production is good. I have opened the discussion on Tailwind Repo (I thought it was a bug of new Tailwind), and no one got the same. I think this is come from the environment of localhost (not clear or something). Finally, I have to switch to Codespace until now. Hope anyone got a solution for helping us.

Comment: I'm also having this issue.. no solution yet.   ->> "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7",

Answer (score 5):

Since JIT mode generates your CSS on-demand by scanning your template files, it’s crucial that you configure the purge option in your **tailwind.config.js** file with all of your template paths, otherwise, your CSS will be empty. replace your purge entry with the following:

```
    purge: ["./public/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}"],
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out this https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#styles-don-t-update-when-saving-content-files

You can also add `TAILWIND_MODE=watch` to your .env file.

I hope it's work because when i delete this, i am also facing same error.

And this warning is fine. It just a message

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue,
After removing all inline tailwind classes and put them in CSS files with `@apply` it gets to work well.

*Maybe tailwind compiles CSS before Next server renders components.*

Answer (score 1):

fixed this, just edit the 'purge' property in your tailwind.config.js file a little by adding the correct path like this
'./public/**/*.html',
'./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',

and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

in Nuxtjs, I added:

```
@import url('tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css');
```

in to file: `~/assets/css/tailwind.css`

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS, tailwind can die if you have `@charset "UTF-8";` in CSS file

Answer (score 0):

In my case tailwind wasn't the problem - it turns out one of my components had a memory leak due to a timer.

Test tailwind on a completely separate page/component and see if the hot-refresh works. If it works on one page and not another - you most likely have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets from your purge links. That's what fixed it for me.

from this:

```
purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"]
```

to this:

```
purge: ["./pages/**/*.js,ts,jsx,tsx", "./components/**/*.js,ts,jsx,tsx"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case Turbopack was the issue. I wanted to try Turbopack and added it like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --turbo"
  },
```

had to change it back to this

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev"
  },
```

hope this helps.